# B field of an EM pulse

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

I am trying to find the B field associated with the following E field (to eventually find the effect it has on a charged particle):
$$E(\vec{x},t)= \Re[E_0(z-ct)]e^{ik_0(z-ct)}$$
Where $E_0$ is an arbitrary function of z-ct.

My thought process was to use the following maxwell equation
$$\nabla \times E=-\partial B/\partial t$$
Which results in (under an assumption that dE/dz << kE)
$$\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}=ik_0E_0(z-ct)e^{ik_0(z-ct)}$$
Now my confusion comes in here:  can I just integrate w.r.t t so that my B field is:
$$B=\Re\left(\hat y \underbrace{\int_0^tdt'}_{-\infty \ to\  t?}\ ik_oE_o(z-ct')e^{ik_0(z-ct')}\right)$$
Looking around, I see the main answers say that  I have to include the current density.  But for my situation, this is 0.  I do not see how that will add any more information to what I have.  Can anyone provide some insight as to how I should proceed.

As an additional question, according to @Rob Jeffries, by B field is correct (and should be left as an indefinite integral).  From this, can I write A as an indefinite integral such that $B=\nabla\times A$ and $E=-\nabla \phi-\partial A/\partial t$ giving:
$$A=\hat{x} \int dt' E_0(z-ct')e^{ik_0(z-ct')}$$

Comment: What's the $E_0(z-ct]$ bit supposed to represent in the wave? For a plane wave, this is usually just left at $E_0$

Comment: ARBITRARY function that would give a pulse.  (Could be gaussian for example)

Answer (score 0):

The integral is indefinite. The result is that you have a B-field which is in phase with, but perpendicular to both the E-field and the direction (z) of wave propagation; whilst the amplitude of the B-field is $c$ times less than the E-field - i.e the basic properties of a transverse electromagnetic wave.

Of course when you have an indefinite integral, there is a constant (in time) of integration. This is correct, since an additional time-independent B-field is entirely consistent with Maxwell's equations.

$$ \vec{B} = \hat{y} \frac{E_{0}(z-ct)}{c}e^{ik_0(z-ct)} + \vec{B}_0(\vec{r}) $$

You can see by inspection that this gives the correct $\partial \vec{B}/\partial t$ *if* you do not neglect (as you have done), the second term in the curl. You also have a sign error in your $\partial \vec{B}/ \partial t$.

Comment: I missed including the vector notation (but I swear I had it :) ) .  Should my indefinite integral have a lower bound of 0 or -infinity then?  Additionally, the E_0 is not specificed, as that would be the pulse part

Comment: @yankeefan11 The integral doesn't need limits.

Comment: You also mention that my magnitudes are related by a factor of c, but I have that |B|/|E| = ko = w/c, not just c.

Comment: @yankeefan11 Then you've got it wrong. Clearly when you integrate, a factor of $-ik_0 c$ appears in the denominator.